# Google Cloud Build Bitbucket integration does not support git tags

Tags: git, bitbucket, google-cloud-build, python-poetry, bitbucket-cloud

Just as you can see in the title, if you configure a CloudBuild trigger to pull a repository from Bitbucket, it will be a mirror and it won't have tags, so build setups that use for example poetry dynamic versions will build packages with version = 0.0.0.

Is anyone knowing if Google is gonna fix it? Do you have a reliable way around it?

PS: With tags I mean `git tag`, the command to tag a commit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you would like Cloud Build to use the flags that you have in your BitBucket repository.

Cloud Build uses the tags that are specified in it's config file. More information about this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#tags).

There is no recommended way to doing this as far as I know. Furthermore what you described seems to be a feature request more than an issue.
I encourage you to create a feature request following [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests). Please make sure to explain how you would like this feature to work and explain the limitations you are encountering.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, but I mean `git tag`, not the tags you can add to the Cloud Build yaml.

Comment: Hello, sorry for misunderstanding. However I think that the best course of action in order to add `git tags` to Cloud Build is still to create a feature request, since there is no way of doing that now, that I'm aware of.